# Vue Quasar - change name of builted generated css

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs3, quasar-framework

Quasar creates two CSS files upon the build:

[image]

I want them to have the names like:

-quasar.css

-appQuasar.css

I have been searching a lot and I can't find any documentation to change the CSS. For example the app file on quasar.config.js

[image]

Thank you,